# Tweetdeck webapp for Firefox

Tags: unity, firefox, chromium, webapps

Twitter bought Tweetdeck. Using Firefox or Chromium, after entering the website http://web.tweetdeck.com/ displays a notification to install Unity interface integration.

Unfortunately this does not work, 
 and really care about notifications, because I got used to those in Chrome, and since Chrome is trying to cut off.

Can you help me?

Comment: Why does this not work? Which error do you get?

Comment: I don't have any error, and I don't have notification's, or any Unity addon, like this:
http://imgur.com/bA3vISM

Comment: Got any lucky with that? I think that Tweetdeck integration with Unity would be great.

Answer (score 1):

I think that Twitter Unity Webapp is configured to use any twitter.com subdomain and since Tweetdeck is a subdomain (tweetdeck.twitter.com), it try to install that one... but doesn't work.

I made a simple Unity Integration for Tweetdeck - it includes the Launcher, Alt+Tab and Dash integration.

Take a look on my Github: https://github.com/eudennis/unity-webapps-tweetdeck
(If anyone know something about Twitter API, could make a deeper integration)